# Is it possible to create `active-backup` bond with Ethernet and Infiniband IPoIB interfaces?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, bonding, infiniband

Is it possible to create L3-level? bonding an Ethernet interface and an Infiniband IPoIB interface on Linux, with `active-backup` where the IPoIB one is the primary? For this, I have set the subnet ranges for Ethernet and Infiniband to be overlapped.